# jQuery Load inside another Load not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a document ready load when I click a button on view.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#admin_user_view").load('admin_modules/user_mgt/pending.php', function(){ //get content from PHP page
        $(".loading-div").hide();
    });

});
</script>
```

The pending.php page also contains another load:

```
$("#pending_view" ).load( "fetch_pages.php?query=admin_user_view&view_page=pending", function(){ //get content from PHP page
        $(".loading-div").hide();
    });
```

The problem is, the loading in pending.php is not working. I also tried:

```
$('#admin_user_view').load('admin_modules/user_mgt/pending.php',
        function(){
            $("#pending_view" ).load( "fetch_pages.php?query=admin_user_view&view_page=pending", function(){ //get content from PHP page
                $(".loading-div").hide();
            });
        });
```

What did I miss? Or is this really not possible? If not possible, what alternative can I do?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Note:** Both the first and the second load functions are wrapped in document ready function and the third one is being called by a function when a button is clicked.

Comment: [The event handling suite](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) also has a method named .load(). jQuery determines which method to fire based on the set of arguments passed to it. [Load data from the server](http://api.jquery.com/load/) I think it's getting confused by it...

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for not double checking everything. The jQuery functions are working perfectly. The problem lies within the PHP code I'm calling inside that load so nothing seems to happen. When I fixed the PHP code, everything worked fine. Thanks for your help!